# Error while trying to sign up for this SE site using Google OpenID

Tags: bug, status-completed

I came to te Buddhism SE site and clicked a vote button as a guest which prompts the user to sign up or log in.

I selected "sign in using Google" as I do on most other SE sites but I received a message from
Google's OpenID system:

> 400 (BAD REQUEST)
>   That’s an error.
>
> OpenID auth request contains an unregistered domain:
>   https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/users/authenticate/
>
> Learn more
>
> That’s all we know.

I was able to successfully link my Google OpenID to the site via this Meta site, but this sounds like an issue with the OpenID registration for this SE site (and possibly others.)

Comment: Looks like we forgot to update that spot when we switched over to Google's new sign-in method. (The old one doesn't work anymore for any new domains and we keep creating new domains when we launch a new site.) I'm on it.

Comment: I have a fix ready locally, but it needs a bit more testing. (Touching login-related code is fun!) Should be able to deploy tomorrow, but in the meantime, use the sign up/login links in the topbar as a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for catching this!

A fix will be rolling out later today. Keep an eye out for revision 2014.7.8.1692, and please report any other login issues you see.

Answer (score 1):

Probably best to raise in [Meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com).

Comment: No need. We check all site metas.

Comment: Awesome, good to know.